# ReactDOM renders only one component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to create an app with comments feature. I am trying with the code like this:

```
response.data.forEach((el, idx, arr) => {
  const newMessage = <CommentMessage username={el.username} message={el.message}/>
  ReactDOM.render(newMessage, this.commentListRef.current)
})
```

I am using MySQL. Axios for HTTP Requests. And Next.js for the framework.

Full code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import styles from './comments-list.module.css'

class CommentMessage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <b>{this.props.username}</b>
            <span>: </span>
            <span>{this.props.message}</span>
        </div>)
    }
}

class CommentsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.commentListRef = React.createRef()

        const comments = []
    }
    loadComments() {
        const axios = require('axios')
        axios.get('/api/getcomments')
            .then(response => {
                response.data.forEach((el, idx, arr) => {
                    const newMessage = <CommentMessage username={el.username} message={el.message}/>
                    ReactDOM.render(newMessage, this.commentListRef.current)
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (<div ref={this.commentListRef} onLoad={this.loadComments()}>

        </div>)
    }
}

export default CommentsList
```

But it only render this:

[image]

Expected this:

[image]

Comment: You should just use ReactDOM.render once, so add them all to an array and render the array. Or create a new component that wraps all the messages and then render this component.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this pretty strangely; I don't know if that's on purpose or not. Regardless, the recommended approach would be to store the comments as part of your component's state, and update the state when you get the comments.

Like this:

```
class CommentsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          comments: []
        };

        this.commentListRef = React.createRef()

        const comments = []
    }
    loadComments() {
        const axios = require('axios')
        axios.get('/api/getcomments')
            .then(response => {
              this.setState({
                comments: response.data
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
      this.loadComments();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (<div ref={this.commentListRef}>
            (this.state.comments.map(comment => (
                <CommentMessage username={comment.username} message={comment.message}/>
            )))
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Also, your onLoad wasn't working as you had expected. It will call loadComments every time the component renders, and I don't even know if onLoad is a proper event on a div.

At any rate, if you absolutely wanted to do it the way you did it, you would have to mount each node into its own container. As you have it right now, each comment is overwriting the contents of commentListRef. So you'd have to create a new element, append that to commentListRef, and mount the react component to that:

```
   loadComments() {
       const axios = require('axios')
       axios.get('/api/getcomments')
           .then(response => {
               response.data.forEach((el, idx, arr) => {
                   const element = document.createElement('div');
                   this.commentListRef.current.appendChild(element);
                   const newMessage = <CommentMessage username={el.username} message={el.message}/>
                   ReactDOM.render(newMessage, element)
               })
           })
           .catch(err => {
               console.log(err)
           })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOM.render` will only render one component for a given container. From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

> Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called. Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.

Basically when you call `ReactDOM.render` in a loop, React is treating each given component as an update to the previous component, rather than rendering each individually.

Best practice is to render a single component at the root container (usually called `<App>`). However it seems you've already done this as these `ReactDOM.render` calls are happening within another component. Generally, you should only need to use `ReactDOM.render` once within an app.

Instead you can store the data in the `CommentsList` component's state and just return the children components from the parent's `render` method.

For example:

```js
class CommentsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            comments: [],
        }
    }

    loadComments = () => {
        const axios = require('axios')
        axios.get('/api/getcomments')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState(prev => ({...prev, comments: response.data}));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    
    render() {
        const { comments } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {comments.map(e => (
                    <CommentMessage key={e.id} username={e.username} message={e.message}/>
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Note: I've also passed a `key` to the `CommentMessage` component to give each child a stable identity (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info). Had to guess, but I assume a comment would have an `id` value, if not, you can choose a different unique value for the comment to use as a key.

Also I'd recommend moving to [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) over class-based components—a lot easier to work with once you get a grasp on hooks.